# Boomerang type loops in Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil, looping

To loop animations with Grease Pencil, I've been using the Time Offset modifier. This is works well when I want to restart the loop from the beginning but it doesn't do well with a "boomerang" type effect.

Say there are four frames that I'd like to repeat: A, B, C, D.

The Time Offset only (seems) to provide A -> B -> C -> D -> A -> B -> C -> D...

What I'd like to get is A -> B -> C -> D -> C -> B -> A -> B -> C -> D...

Is there a way to do this without manually copying frames?

Comment: Have you tried using modulo?  https://exceljet.net/articles/how-to-use-the-mod-function-to-repeat-values

Comment: you can animate the frame offset value and add a Cycles modifier in the Graph editor set to "Repeat Mirrored"

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to rig something up by using the time offset mode "chain" rather than "regular".  With chain you can stack different orders one after the other using the segments.